# Get all the dates from database

Tags: java, database, realm

I am storing objects with timestamp in the database(Realm).

```
public class Met extends RealmObject{
    private String name;
    private int met;
    private long timestamp;
}
```

I want to show them date wise, like grouping them by date.

Since it is a timestamp and will be different for rows of the same day, I am not able to get it to work.

This comes from the backend and I cannot change it to date.

The only idea I have is to add an extra date field, so that it would be easy to query.

Is there a way to achieve this at the query level without any extra fields?

Comment: it mostly looks like database question, you should give the schema of table as well.

Comment: @Mritunjay I am actually using Realm, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

To query by the same day, you could easily set up a query that queries between the start of the day and the start of the next day.

```
public class Met extends RealmObject {
    private String name;
    private int met;
    @Index
    private long timestamp;
}
```

And

```
Date startOfDay = //...get start of day
Date startOfNextDay = //... get start of next day;
RealmResults<Met> mets = realm.where(Met.class)
                              .greaterThanOrEqualTo(MetFields.TIMESTAMP, startOfDay.getTime())
                              .lessThan(MetFields.TIMESTAMP, startOfNextDay.getTime())
                              .findAllSorted(MetFields.TIMESTAMP, Sort.ASCENDING);
```